# Magento Generate Report for the Orders Created from Admin Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to generate the report for the orders created from the admin, How do I generate the report for the order created from within the admin panel.

The only logic I found was the order created from admin donot have "IP placed From: blank", the frontend placed order do have "IP Placed From: 100.100.100.100" for eg.

Any hints to create a separate  module for this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can isolate the orders with an empty IP address.
Where you put this code....that's your decision. It depends on how you are trying to build your report.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('remote_ip', array('null'=>true));
```